# Angularjs download image and display

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to download an image with Angularjs and then save it to mongodb and display it in the future.

First I just try to download image binary and display it and it doesn't work.

```
$scope.downloadProfileImage = function()
    {
        //Getting the user that logged in through facebook
        $authentication.getUserInfoWithoutLocation(function(respone)
        {
            //getting the url for the profile picture from facebook
            FB.api('/'+respone.id+'/picture',function(respone)
            {
                //the response hold the url of the profile picutre..trying to download it
                $http.get(respone.data.url).success(function(success)
                {
                    //success is the image binary,encoding it to base64 and bound to it
                    $scope.img = Base64.encode(success)
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

in the html I just have `<img ng-src="{{img}}"/>`.

this doesn't work.. why?
even if I remove the base64 encoding and bind $scope.img to success it still does now show the image..

please help me.

Thanks!.

Comment: In `ng-src`, the value should be without `interpolation` means `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display an image encoded in base64 it has to be in following form:

```
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

So you probably have to add `data:image/png;base64,` in front of your `$scope.img`. Of course it depends what your image format is (png, jpeg, gif).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the URL in `ngSrc`?

```
FB.api('/'+respone.id+'/picture',function(respone)
{
    $scope.imgSrc = respone.data.url;
});
```

View

```
<img ng-src="{{ imgSrc }}" />
```

Comment: No, because i want to download the picture and save it on the server and in the future fetch and display, so in the server i will save the base64 of the image but i cant display it

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether the image is successfully encoded into base64 or not. I think so. Now before displaying it just add this "data:image/png;base64," to the base64 string.
Here is the sample

In angularjs file

```
$scope.picValue="data:image/png;base64,"+base64String;
```

In html page

```
<img ng-src="{{picValue}}" />
```